# Android: constants vs. resources

Tags: java, android, resources, constants

When writing an Android application, what is the preferred method to store constant values, define them programatically at the beginning of a class (e.g. final int ...), or define them as resources (e.g. in abc.xml) and reference them when needed.

Part of my code involves a unit converter, so I want to store conversion factors and text strings for each unit. I'll only be referencing the values from a single class.

I'm looking for an answer both from a style/consistency viewpoint and a performance viewpoint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources will be preferable it gives you support for multiple languages. Lets take an example in US they have miles as unit, but China have some thing else. So, you not need to worry for writing a code and finding out which one to display, you can create separate resources for each language and android will take care for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you! I feel stupid now, because I just recently read the tutorial on resources, and the auto-selection of appropriate language etc. resources was one of the topics covered.